# QGIS python script crashed with minidump written to C

Tags: qgis, python, error, minidump, ppygis

I have written a python script which has two input vector layers (one point-layer and one line-layer). The outpout is another line-layer. But when I try too set the geometry for the new edge, the python script stopps and I get the error "minidump written to C".

Here is my python script code:

```
# name :  MergeEdges_script
# date   : 22.10.2018
# description: merges edges with the same edgeid
#           and adds two attributes for speed limits on each lane 

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from math import degrees

#***********Constants*************#
EDGEID = 'edgeid'
FROM = 'from'
TO = 'to'
PRIORITY = 'priority'
LENGTH = 'length'
TIME = 'time'

ID = 'id'
VTO = 'vto'
VFROM = 'vfrom'
NODE1 = 'node1'
NODE2 = 'node2'
#*******************************#

# input parameters 
##Edges=vector
##Nodes=vector

inLayerEdges = processing.getObject(Edges)
inNodes = processing.getObject(Nodes)

crs = inLayerEdges.crs().toWkt()

# get field indices for inputlayer
idxEdgeId = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(ID)
idxPriority = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(PRIORITY)
idxLength  = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(LENGTH)
idxTime    = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(TIME)
idxFrom  = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(FROM)
idxTo  = inLayerEdges.fieldNameIndex(TO)

idx_id = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(NODEID)
idx_x = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(COORD_X)
idx_y = inNodes.fieldNameIndex(COORD_Y)

# Create output layer and specify geometry type
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs=' + crs, 'merged_edges', 'memory')
# Set the provider to accept the data source
outdp = outLayer.dataProvider()

# define attributes and add them to the vector layer
outdp.addAttributes([QgsField(EDGEID, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(NODE1, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(NODE2, QVariant.String),
                        QgsField(PRIORITY, QVariant.Int),
                        QgsField(VTO, QVariant.Double),
                        QgsField(VFROM, QVariant.Double)])
outLayer.updateFields()

# get field indices for outputlayer
outEdgeId = outdp.fieldNameIndex(EDGEID)
outNode1 = outdp.fieldNameIndex(NODE1)
outNode2 = outdp.fieldNameIndex(NODE2)
outPriority = outdp.fieldNameIndex(PRIORITY)
outVTo = outdp.fieldNameIndex(VTO)
outVFrom = outdp.fieldNameIndex(VFROM)

listOfEdgeIds = []
count = 0
flag = 0

# loop through edges of inLayerEdges and merge 
for feat in inLayerEdges.getFeatures():

  # create new edge (line) for outputLayer
  newEdge = QgsFeature(outLayer.pendingFields())

  currentPriority = feat.attributes()[idxPriority]
  currentEdgeId = feat.attributes()[idxEdgeId]

  if currentEdgeId.find('From') == -1:
      edgeIdTrimmed = currentEdgeId.replace('To', '')
  else:
      edgeIdTrimmed = currentEdgeId.replace('From', '')

  if edgeIdTrimmed in listOfEdgeIds:
      # if current edge id already processed -> skip it.
      #print "current edgeid already in list. Continue ..."
      continue

  else:      
      # if not, find all entries in the graph which share the same current edge id
      # and merge them
      listOfEdgeIds.append(edgeIdTrimmed)

      newEdge.setAttribute(EDGEID, edgeIdTrimmed)
      newEdge.setAttribute(PRIORITY, currentPriority)

      node1 = feat.attributes()[idxFrom]
      node2 = feat.attributes()[idxTo]
      newEdge.setAttribute(NODE1, node1)
      newEdge.setAttribute(NODE2, node2)

      # search for specific from_node by nodeID
      exp = QgsExpression('nodeID ILIKE \'' + node1 +'\' ')
      request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
      request.setLimit(1)

      for feat2 in inNodes.getFeatures(request):
          geomFrom = feat2.geometry()
          print geomFrom

      # search for specific to_node by nodeID
      exp = QgsExpression('nodeID ILIKE \'' + node2 +'\' ')
      request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
      request.setLimit(1)

      for feat2 in inNodes.getFeatures(request):
          geomTo = feat2.geometry()
          print geomTo

      # find all entries in the graph with current edge id
      exp = QgsExpression('id ILIKE \'' + edgeIdTrimmed + '%\' ')
      request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)

      # loop through all egdes with the same current edgeids
      for feat1 in inLayerEdges.getFeatures(request):

          tempEdgeId = feat1.attributes()[idxEdgeId]

          length = feat1.attributes()[idxLength]
          time    = feat1.attributes()[idxTime]
          velocity = (length / time) * 3.6

          if tempEdgeId.find("From") is not -1:
              #print("Python found the string From!")
              newEdge.setAttribute(VFROM, velocity)
          elif tempEdgeId.find("To") is not -1:
              #print("Python found the string To!")
              newEdge.setAttribute(VTO, velocity)
          else:
              print("Python did NOT find the substring!")


    newEdge.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline
      ([geomFrom.asPoint(),geomTo.asPoint()]))
    # add the feature to the layer
    (res, outFeats) = outdp.addFeatures([newEdge])


# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
print "Done ... "
```

With the help of printf-Debugging, I have figured out that the crash is caused by this line:

```
        newEdge.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geomFrom.asPoint(),geomTo.asPoint()]))
```

I have already deleted the .qgis2-folder and started qgis 2.18 anew. But without success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely hitting the famous [issue 777](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/777)

There are 2 possibilities to get around this:

1. Upgrade to QGIS 3
2. Make sure the geometry is saved to a variable and not passed as temporary to keep the python garbage collector happy

---

```
geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geomFrom.asPoint(),geomTo.asPoint()])
newEdge.setGeometry(geom)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your 2. suggestions hasn't solved the problem, so I will try it by upgrading to QGIS3. I will let you know if I was able to solve the issue.